# turn off alerts on an announcement list

Tags: powershell, alert

How can I disable email alerts for an announcement list (that is, prevent users from signing up for alerts on this list)? I looked at the list settings in the UI, but did not see a way to do this. I also searched online for a PowerShell approach, but only found a way to [disable email alerts for an entire web application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287751.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ready to override permissions for that list, you may create custom permission level(s) and remove "Create Alerts" permission from that permission level(s).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to disable alerts just for a single list in a user-friendly manner.  There are some rough workarounds you could do though, depending on how badly you need these blocked ...

- Write a Timer job to delete any alerts created for the blocked list.  This is very ugly from a user experience as it lets people think they successfully created alerts but it accomplishes what you are looking to do.
- Use a [URL Rewriter](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) tool to intercept the Subscribe To Alert page for that specific list and redirect the users to a friendlier "Not allowed" page.  This is better but still not ideal.  It also requires more manual work as the rewrites have to be managed by hand on each server in the farm